# Not able to create Collation on windows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Hi I am trying to create collation on Windows but not able to create it, I getting error as shown in screenshot.

[image]

[image]

I am using deafult POSIX collation to create new collation,

Here on Postgres website, It is mentioned that POSIX is available in all platform.

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/collation.html
>
> On all platforms, the collations named default, C, and POSIX are
>   available. Additional collations may be available depending on
>   operating system support. The default collation selects the LC_COLLATE
>   and LC_CTYPE values specified at database creation time. The C and
>   POSIX collations both specify "traditional C" behavior, in which only
>   the ASCII letters "A" through "Z" are treated as letters, and sorting
>   is done strictly by character code byte values.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is unexpected and could be seen as a bug, you might want to report it.

The underlying problem is that Windows does not know a locale `POSIX`. What is surprising here is that the pre-existing collation `POSIX` has `POSIX` set as `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` even though they do not exist.

However, you can easily work around the problem since collation `C` is the same as `POSIX`:

```
CREATE COLLATION test FROM pg_catalog."C";
```